# FluentMvcTesting using ShouldReturnJson with a JSON Array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using FluentMvcTesting from TestStack to test the following controller action that returns JSON.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetFoos(int fooOwnerId)
{
   var foos = GetFoosForOwner(fooOwnerId);
   return Json(foos.Select(x => new {x.FooId,x.Foo.Name}),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

which returns `[{\"FooId\":1,\"Name\":\"Foo1\"},\"FooId\":2,\"Name\":\"Foo2\"}]` but getting

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

in the test

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetFoos()
{
    _controller.WithCallTo(c => c.GetFoos(_model.OwnerId)).ShouldReturnJson(data =>
    {
       Assert.AreEqual("Foo1", data[0].Name);
    });
}
```

If I do this though, it works

```
var json = Json.Encode(data);
Assert.AreEqual("[{\"FooId\":1,\"Name\":\"Foo1\"},\"FooId\":2,\"Name\":\"Foo2\"}]",json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data contained in your `JsonResult` is of `IEnumerable<>` type and doesn't define an indexer.

Try to convert it to something that implements `ICollection`, for example:

```
foos.Select(x => new {x.FooId,x.Foo.Name}).ToArray();
// or
foos.Select(x => new {x.FooId,x.Foo.Name}).ToList();
```

(Also, since the `data` parameter in the `Action` you're passing to `ShouldReturnJson()` is `dynamic`, you're only encountering the problem on run-time)

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: Using ToArray() I get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Comment: @ASG What are the parameters defined in your `ShouldReturnJson()` method?

Comment: `public JsonResult ShouldReturnJson(Action<dynamic> assertion)` from https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.FluentMVCTesting/blob/00ce0046254f4d29afe94fe7e1237879a1fc75c1/TestStack.FluentMvcTesting/ControllerResultTest/ShouldReturnJson.cs#L14

Comment: Put a break-point before the call to `Assert.AreEqual`, what are the types of `data` and its elements?

Comment: `data {<>f__AnonymousType1d<int,string>[2]} dynamic {<>f__AnonymousType1d<int,string>[]}`
 then `[0] { FooId = 1, Name = "Foo1" } <Anonymous Type>` and `[1] { FooId = 2, Name = "Foo2" } <Anonymous Type>`